# Having Issues AVG Time

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am having issues averaging time, I tried to average it, I tried to convert it and then average it. The one thing that looked like it would work is not supported on Redshift SQL.

Tried to convert the time and averaging the time, but neither succeeded

```
Select 
  date,
  "agent name",
  (TO_CHAR((sum("handle time") || 'second')::interval,'MI.SS')) as total,
  (TO_CHAR((avg("handle time") || 'second')::interval,'MI.SS'))as AVGHandleTime
From five9_data.calllog
Where Skill in ('SF Sales', 'FYF Sales') 
Group By "agent name", date
Order By Date DESC
Limit 100
```

I am trying to retrieve the average call time for each individual for a given period of time. I am new to sql and apologize if I am missing something. for example 4:36 (MM:SS) would result in 4.6 as a decimal. I hope this question is much more clear than my last.

**Handle Time Values**
00:17:00,
00:18:13,
00:01:55,
00:05:40,

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL to me.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: What is the data type of `"handle time"`? Can you share an example of a few of those values that you would be averaging?

Comment: Handle time comes in standard time format MM:SS. This is Redshift SQL but it doesn't come up when I enter it, only the data warehousing.

Comment: It comes in that format, but what is the data type of the column in which it is stored?

Comment: VARCHAR is the data type. Sorry.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to supply some sample values in the `handle time` column?

Comment: ahhh, I messed up the format because the way my query worked, it only showed mm:ss, when it is realy hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your time is stored as a varchar and there is no `Time` or `Interval` type in Redshift, you'll have to convert that `mm:ss` into a number so that you can take the average (as you can't average a string/varchar).

You can use function `SPLIT_PART` to split the string specifying a delimiter and retrieve a portion of it, then apply some math to get you decimal representation of your time:

```
SELECT date,
  "agent name",
  avg(SPLIT_PART("handle time", ':', 1)::decimal(18,2)*60.00 + SPLIT_PART("handle time", ':', 2)::decimal(18,2) + SPLIT_PART("handle time", ':', 3)::decimal(18,2)/60.00) as AvgHandleTime
From five9_data.calllog
Where Skill in ('SF Sales', 'FYF Sales') 
Group By "agent name", date
Order By Date DESC
Limit 100;
```

I don't have a redshift instance to test that on, but it should get you in the ballpark.

UPDATED: I have updated to account for `hh:mm:ss` format. Here we convert to minutes in decimal form (as we were before).

Comment: Thank you, I am in the ballpark, going to try and work this out from here. Thank you.

Comment: Because my formatting was off, this will be off, it is actually, hh:mm:ss.

Comment: I have updated the answer to account for `hh:mm:ss` format. Still converting to number of minutes in decimal form and taking the average.

Comment: That is perfect thank you for the help, now I have to sit down and try to understand what you did. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date,
  "agent name",
  avg(SPLIT_PART("handle time", ':', 1)*60 + SPLIT_PART("handle time", ':', 2)::decimal(18,2) + SPLIT_PART("handle time", ':', 3)::decimal(18,2)/60.00) as AvgHandleTime
From five9_data.calllog
Where Skill in ('SF Sales', 'FYF Sales') 
Group By "agent name", date
Order By Date DESC
Limit 100;